# Initializing AVAudioPlayer with an iPod Song URL Using initWithContentsOfURL

Tags: ios, background, avaudioplayer, initwithcontentsofurl

I know it is possible to play iPod Songs using AVPlayer, but I cannot figure out how to initialize the `AVAudioPlayer` with an iPod song URL using `initWithContentsOfURL`. When I try, the `AVAudioPlayer` returns NULL upon initialization.

I need to use `AVAudioPlayer` because I need to use its delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` for further processing when my app runs in the background (i.e. the `AVAudioPlayer` delegate method `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` gets called if the app is running in the background. But the `AVPlayer` does not provide delegate methods, so you can only use notifications which don't run in the background).

The following code is for playing an iPod song with the AVPlayer.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [session setActive:YES error:&error];
    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    NSArray *collection = [query items];
    MPMediaItem *item = [collection objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",[item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]);
    NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url];   // <-- Line to Replace
    [player play];
}
```

This works great. But if I replace the second to last line with the following:

```
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
```

the call to `initWithContentsOfURL` returns NULL.

Any thoughts about why this returns NULL when I use `AVAudioPlayer`, but returns an initialized player when I use `AVPlayer`?

According the the Technical Q&A http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1634/_index.html, "the URL used with initWithContentsOfURL: must be a File URL (file://). That is, a local path."

When I obtain the url for the song in my iPod Library, the path is:

ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-4017276016911605928

Would you say that this path to my iPod library is not considered a "local path" or would you consider it a bug that `initWithContentsOfURL` is returning NULL?

Thoughts anyone?

Comment: any solution to this ? i am doing the same in Swift but no luck . . can you please tell how to make the above url as a local url

Comment: @UsamaSadiq Sorry, but as you can see from the answer below, there does not seem to be a solution (at least none that works for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sort of answered your own question because from what I can gather it is the url path that is important for `AVAudioPlayer`, and it has to be local to the bundle.  There is an example of using `AVPlayer` with notifications, search `AVPlayerDemo` for `playerItemDidReachEnd` but I cannot tell you whether it runs in background or foreground.

Comment: ok, thanks. I did not know that the url path had to be local to the bundle. Good to know. Unfortunately, notifications from AVPlayer are withheld when the app is in the background until it reenters the foreground, so that won't help

Comment: I think it's ambiguous whether "local" means "in the bundle" or "on the device." AVAudioPlayer initWithContentsOfURL with an ipod-library URL seems to work fine in iOS 6 and 7, but I don't see any official documentation or explanation of this change.